# Inclusion of both inclusive and exclusive range in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

i have the following table generated by SQL TABLE A

```
timeinterval   count(exclusive range)
0-6             2
0-12            5
0-18            10
```

i want a table like this TABLE B

```
timeinterval   count(exclusive range)  count(inclusive range)
1-6             2                       2
1-12            5                       3
1-18            10                      5
```

i have already generated table A and need table B. can i do something in SQL where i can add a query in the code for table A and do something like this (0-12)-(0-6) for 2nd row in table B.

code used for generating table A is

```
with ranges as 
  (
    select 6 as val, 1 as count_all
 union all
    select 12, 1
    union all
    select 18, 1
    union all
 select 24, 1
    union all
 select 30, 1
    union all  
 select 36, 1
    union all 
 select 42, 1
    union all
 select 48, 1
    union all   
 select 1, 0
  )
select case when ranges.count_all = 0
            then 'more'
            else  convert (varchar(10), ranges.val) 
        end [MetLifeExperienceMonths],
       sum (case when (ranges.count_all = 0 and GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths>=1)
                   or
           (GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths<= ranges.val and  GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths>=1)
                 then 1 end) [count],
count(EmployeeID) as 'Total'
into yy
from GoldListHistogram
cross join ranges
where MetLifeExperienceMonths > 0
group by ranges.val, ranges.count_all
```

*i need to modify the query such that i can subtract first two rows value for "count(exclusive range)" for every row staring from the 2nd row..like for 0-12(time interval) row i need to output a value that is difference of the first two rows..like row(i)=count(i)-count(i-1).*

first column gives the time interval in 5 years (in months) second column calculates no. of employees in the exclusive range like (0-6,0-12,0-18)..6 ,12,18 being no. of months third column calculates no. of employees in the exclusive range like (0-6,6-12,12-18)

Comment: Yep, I have *no* idea how those values in the new column are calculated from the existing data.

Comment: @AnandPhadke i need to modify the query such that i can subtract first two rows value for "count(exclusive range)" for every row staring from the 2nd row..like for 0-12(time interval) row i need to output a value that is difference of the first two rows..like row(i)=count(i)-count(i-1). please let me know if this was of any help :(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is there any other way i can achieve my desired table from the table i have already generated?

Comment: @SQLify your comment should be added on the question, edit it and explain yourself there, that way you will get more chances of getting some answer

Comment: You haven't explained what the second column's values are meant to *represent*. The words "count(inclusive range)" don't convey adequate information to me. I can produce a query that, given the *exact* input you've provided, will produce the *exact* output you say you want, but that's just hard coding constant values.

Comment: how are you calculating inclusive rang?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever exactly why i am in a tiff because i dnt want to hard code constant values. i want to keep it as dynamic and as reusable as possible.
first column gives the time interval in 5 years (in months)
second column calculates no. of employees in the exclusive range like (0-6,0-12,0-18)..6 ,12,18 being no. of months
third column calculates no. of employees in the exclusive range like (0-6,6-12,12-18)

Comment: @AnandPhadke i am not calculating inclusive range here. all i am doing is calculate the exclusive ranges' count and trying to fetch the desired output(inclusive range) from it.
because i am not quite able to group both inclusive and exclusive ranges inside the same table using SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just add a start value to ranges?  Something like:

```
with ranges as 
  (
    select 6 as val, 0 as start, 1 as count_all
 union all
    select 12, 7, 1
    union all
    select 18, 13, 1
    union all
 select 24, 19, 1
    union all
 select 30, 25, 1
    union all  
 select 36, 31, 1
    union all 
 select 42, 37, 1
    union all
 select 48, 43, 1
    union all   
 select 1, 49, 0
  )
select case when ranges.count_all = 0
            then 'more'
            else  convert (varchar(10), ranges.val) 
        end [MetLifeExperienceMonths],
       sum (case when (ranges.count_all = 0 and GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths>=1)
                   or
           (GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths=1)
                 then 1 else 0 end) [count inclusive],
       sum (case when (ranges.count_all = 0 and GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths>=1)
                   or
           (GoldListHistogram.MetLifeExperienceMonths=ranges.start)
                 then 1 else 0 end) [count exclusive],
count(EmployeeID) as 'Total'
into yy
from GoldListHistogram
cross join ranges
where MetLifeExperienceMonths > 0
group by ranges.val, ranges.count_all;
```